# Typeahead.js prefetch option not working

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js

I am unable to get the prefetch option to work in typeahead.js.  Local data works fine.  Answers to previously posted questions suggest that caching could be an issue, but I have set the ttl to 0 and am testing in private browsing mode in Firefox and Chrome.  What am I missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://twitter.github.com/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://twitter.github.com/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.js"></script>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#searchText').typeahead([
    {
      name: 'terms',
      //local: ["United States", "Canada"],
      prefetch: 'http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/data/countries.json',
      ttl: 0
      }
    ]);
  });
</script>

<body>
<div class="container">
  <input class="typeahead" type="text" id="searchText">
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @PauloTomé Don't use backticks that way. They are not for highlighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always check the `console` (Firebug / Chrome dev tools) when something is "not working", it's your best friend when working with JS.

In this case, it's not that `prefetch` is not working. But Github doesn't allow you to fetch that json from different domain. If you check your console, you will see this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/data/countries.json. Origin http://yourdomain is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

So if you want to get this example working locally, you should download that JSON file and set it up locally, then change the URL a bit like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#searchText').typeahead({
        name: 'terms',
        prefetch: '/data/countries.json', // go to http//yourdomain/data/countries to make sure the path is correct
        ttl: 0
    });
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That does help, thank you.  For whatever reason, I am not seeing that error message in the console section of Firebug, but when I switch to Chrome I do see that message.  Thank you for your help.